# Baffling "Useless use of a constant in void context" in simple code

Tags: perl, bash, warnings

I'm executing a small Perl script inside a Bash script.  Perl reports **Useless use of a constant in void context at -e line 28**, which is *after* the end of the Perl code.

The Bash excerpt:

```
#
# Perl script to parse album list file
#
PERLSCRIPT=$( cat <<-'__END__'

    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use XML::Simple;


    my $albums_file      = $ARGV[0];
    my $album_id         = $ARGV[1];

    my $albums_data = XMLin ( $albums_file,
                              forcearray => [ 'Album' ] );
    my $album_key   = "";

    foreach my $album ( keys %{$albums_data->{Albums}->{Album}} )
    {
        if ( $album == $album_id )
        {
            $album_key = $albums_data->{Albums}->{Album}
                                           ->{$album}->{Key};
            print "$album_key\n";
            exit 0;
        }
    }

    exit 1;

'__END__' )


say "$LINENO: Calling perl"
ALBUM_KEY=$(perl -e "$PERLSCRIPT" "$ALBUMS_FILE" "$ALBUM_ID")
```

When executed, I see the following:

```
    454: Calling perl
    Useless use of a constant in void context at -e line 28.
```

What is Perl complaining about?

Comment: Why not put the Perl source in a separate file and call that?

Comment: Apparently it refers to your `'__END__'` token.

Comment: To answer **squiguy**, I want to create a Bash script that is as self-contained as possible.  I'd like others to be able to download it and have it just work, without needing multiple separate files to be installed in the path and made executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it refers to the line with `'__END__'`. The single quotes are not needed with bash's `<<-'TOKEN'` heredoc notation.

```
$ perl -w <<-'__END__'
> print "hello world\n";
> '__END__'
> __END__
Useless use of a constant (__END__) in void context at - line 2.
hello world

$ perl -w <<-'__END__'
> print "hello world\n";
> __END__
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd added those in a futile effort to get [http://www.shellcheck.net](ShellCheck) to stop complaining about not being able to find the end of the HEREDOC.